# A quick question about continuous functions with compact support

Tags: integration, general-topology, functional-analysis

[image]

Hey, I am currently reading Analysis Now by Pedersen. When he is saying that $C_c(X)$ is stable under lattice operations is he saying that if $\{f_i\}_{i \in I} \subset C_c(X)$, then $f_1, f_2 \in C_c(X)$ where $f_1(x) := \sup \{f_i(x):i \in I\}$ and $f_2(x) := \inf \{f_i(x):i \in I\}$. Same thing with $C_c(X)^m$?

Comment: It is not true that $\sup$ and $\inf$ of all subfamilies of $C_c(X)$ are in $C_c(X)$. See for instance $X=\Bbb R$ and $f_\lambda(x)=\min\{1,\max\{\lambda-\lvert x\rvert,0\}\}$, for which $f_\lambda\nearrow 1\notin C_c(\Bbb R)$. What's true is that $f\wedge g$ and $f\vee g$ are in $C_c(X)$ as soon as $f,g\in C_c(X)$.

Comment: The lattice ooerations, as well multiplication and addition, are two argument operations. The space $C_c(X)$ is not stable under infinite additions.

Comment: Oh I see, he used the bigger version earlier of $\land$ and $\lor$ with an arbitrary collection, so that's why I got confused.

Answer (score 1):

Pedersen introduces the concept of a lattice in section 1.1.1 on p.2.

$C_c(X)$ has a natural order ($f \le g$ iff $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x \in X$). It is a lattice because any pair of functions $f, g \in  C_c(X)$ has a smallest majorant which is the function $f \vee g = \max(f,g)$ and a largest minorant which is the function $f \wedge g = \min(f,g)$.

$C_c(X)^m$ is obtained from $C_c(X)$ by adding the limits of monotone increasing nets in $C_c(X)$. In general these limits are no bounded functions (as $\sup f_\lambda(x) = \infty$ is possible) and do not have compat carrier. The situation for $C_c(X)_m$ is similar.

Comment: Oh I am starting to understand. In the second paragraph, what's the point of using the $\bigwedge$ and $\bigvee$? On page 27, he used them to describe the $\sup$ and $\inf$ of an arbitrary collection of functions. The reason why I ask this since $C_c(X)$ is just a lattice, not a complete one. If $C_c(X)^m$ is stable under $\sup$ of an arbitrary collection, then does that imply $\inf$?

Comment: @3jiwiojr3 Whar Pedersen does on p.27 has nothing to do with $C_c(X)$. He considers the set $C^{1/2}(X)$ of lower semicontinuous functions on $X$. Unfortunately $\bigvee f_j$ has not been explicitly defined in the book (I hope I did not overlook something om pages 1 - 26). But from the context it is clear that it denotes the supremum of the $f_j$. This can be defined as *the smallest majorant* for each ordered set, though its **existence** is not guaranteed. The set $C^{1/2}(X)$ is closed under $\bigvee$, but $C_c(X)$ is not. This is why we extend $C_c(X)$ to $C_c(X)^m$.

Comment: oh I know that on page 27 he was talking about lower semicontinuous functions instead $C_c(X)$. I only brought that up for an example that used $\bigwedge$. I was just wondering why in the second paragraph of the screenshot he used $\bigwedge$ instead of $\wedge$(Since $C_c(X)$ is not stable under $\bigwedge$ and that he used both types of wedges earlier). But, everything else I think I understand. Thanks for help